# Bhattacharya distance between R,G,B Y Cb Cr components of two images

Tags: histogram, distance

I have 2 images taken from two different cameras and  I have to associate an object in both images. I have separated RGB ycbcr components and calculated the histogram of each component separately from both images

Then I concatenated histograms of all components into one vector.

- I have already normalized each histogram separately so that `sum(h)=1;`
- But when I have concatenated all histograms sum of that `vector= 6`.
  and
- when I applied Bhattacharya distance on both vectors the result is in range 4 and 5.

I cannot understand the similarity results because as per my knowledge result of Bhattacharya distance is 0-1

Please help

Answer (score 0):

the best  Bhattacharya distance is 2;
it is Jeffreys-Matusita distance that measure of Battachaya distance
if you have 2 class and the Jeffreys-Matusita was near 2 its good for classification and if it war near 0 the classes are same